# In Java/Swing, what's the difference between ButtonModel's isRollover() and isArmed() methods?

Tags: java, swing

In the Java/Swing API's [ButtonModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonModel.html) interface, what's the difference between the Rollover and Armed properties?  Reading the code and docs, it looks like they're both updated by the same event (mouse entering or exiting the component), but the armed value affects whether or not releasing the mouse button results in an ActionEvent being fired, whereas the Rollover property is just visual.  Is there any situation where a ButtonModel would be armed but not rolled over, or vice-versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the docs correctly the Rollover state indicates that the user is over the button and has pressed the mouse button. So usually you will have Pressed and Armed at the same time.

Rollover triggers whenever the user moves the mouse over the button like :hover in css for example.

Comment: Press the mouse on the button and drag outside the active area to see the `armed` state change to `!armed`.

Answer (score 0):

Rollover means the cursor is above it, but armed means its been clicked but not released or dragged outside the bounds.  Subtle difference, but its there.